# Universal Analytics: How to track conversions when URL doesn't change?

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-ads-api, universal

I'm in the process of upgrading a couple of sites to Universal Analytics and need some help setting up goals for conversion tracking...

I am now using auto event tracking (click listener) to see where users are clicking on the sites' forms, but I'm not sure how I can create goals for form submissions as the URL does not change. (Previously I was sending virtual pageviews when the submit button was clicked, but I don't think it's possible to do this in Universal Analytics?)

I know by using the click listener I can still see how many times the submit button of the form is clicked, but I need to set this up as a goal so I can monitor the cost per conversion of my AdWords campaigns.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You mention you are using auto-event tracking (click listener). Are you using Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Yes @Blexy, I am using Tag Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**loop**, if you are using GTM, you can simply use *Form Submit Listener*:

[image]

**This listener then could fire an event tracking, which will serve as the condition for any conversion goals you might need.** Just keep in mind when setting the conditions for goals, **ALL** of the Event-related dimensions (category, action, label) need to match, even though you can use only one (for example category = form submitted) as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Petr. And what about in situations where clicking on a button doesn't register as a form submission? I have a different form where I am using the click listener - this shows the element id of each button in analytics, but clicking the button I want to create a goal for doesn't result in a form submission. Is it possible to set up a goal for this or do I need to ask our web developer to change how the form is set up? Cheers!

Comment: loop - instead of form listener, you could use click listener and then add a condition to your rule that will check if the clicked element is the one you want to track (for example using {{element id}} or {{element classes}}...

Comment: Hello again @Petr. I think I'm getting closer but not quite there yet. .. For some reason, the final "Quote Me" button of my form is not firing the click listener tag. Our developer has added this code to the button and it is now showing in my Analytics events as "quote":

<a id="quote" href="#" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'quote'});"></a>

I have tried setting up tag manager so it fires when {{element id}} equals "quote", but this isn't working. How do I tell tag manager to  fire when using the dataLayer.push instead??? Appreciate the help.

Comment: @theloop - simply add *event* equals *quote* which should do the trick. no need to bother with event listeners

Comment: OK @Petr I think I follow. So I will get rid of the click lister tag I made specifically for the quote button but leave the line of code mentioned above? But where exactly do you mean to add "event equals quote"? Please bear with me!

Comment: event qeuals quote is a rule which will trigger the tag. once you push the button, a new "event" called "quote" will be added to dataLayer and if you then setup a rule with condition (event equeals quote), it will trigger that tag. hope this makes sense :)